# Redirection not happening from IdentityServer4 after Login to client vuejs application with Implicit grand flow

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

I getting below exception -in implicit mode with vue.js

> This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://localhost:5000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DVuejs%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8484%252Flogin%26response_type%3Did_token%2520token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520courses%2520roles%2520country%2520GPSSchoolAPI%26state%3D5b7f679b185642db87a745f649dab48f%26nonce%3D9f222f460a974434a6d0a7179d79765a might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG

Log on console

```
Executed action method TIS.IdentityServer.Controllers.Account.AccountController.Login (TIS.IdentityServer), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectResult in 65364.2974ms.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectResultExecutor[1]
Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /connect/authorize/callback?client_id=Vuejs&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8484%2Flogin&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20courses%20roles%20country%20GPSSchoolAPI&state=5b7f679b185642db87a745f649dab48f&nonce=9f222f460a974434a6d0a7179d79765a.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
Executed action TIS.IdentityServer.Controllers.Account.AccountController.Login (TIS.IdentityServer) in 65380.1296ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
Executed endpoint 'TIS.IdentityServer.Controllers.Account.AccountController.Login (TIS.IdentityServer)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
Request finished in 65421.3075ms 302
```

configuration

```js
export const oidcSettings = {
    authority: 'http://localhost:5000',
    client_id: 'Vuejs',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8484/login',
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    scope:'openid profile courses roles country GPSSchoolAPI',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8484/index.html',
    //userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore(),
    loadUserInfo: true,
    filterProtocolClaims: true
  }
```

landing component

```js
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
    export default {
        name: "login",
        data: () => {
            return {
                IsLogin: true,
                IsForgotPassword: false,
                //loginleftbg: 'http://localhost/my-project2/src/assets/images/login_side_bg.png',
                LogoUrl: process.env.ROOT_API_IMG + 'logo.png',
                regionalIcon: process.env.userTypeIconPath + 'regional-head.png',
                ceoIcon: process.env.userTypeIconPath + 'ceo.png',
                principalIcon: process.env.userTypeIconPath + 'principal.png',
                teacherIcon: process.env.userTypeIconPath + 'teacher.png',
                studentIcon: process.env.userTypeIconPath + 'student.png',
                parentIcon: process.env.userTypeIconPath + 'parent.png',
                governmentIcon: process.env.userTypeIconPath + 'government.png'

            }
        },
        methods: {
            NavigateTo(name, uuid) {
                this.$router.push({name: name, params: {uuid: uuid}});
            },
            
             ...mapActions( [
                'oidcSignInCallback'
             ])

        },
         computed:{
      ...mapGetters([
        'oidcUser'
      ])
    },
    created(){
       
       this.oidcSignInCallback()
      .then((redirectPath) => {
         
    // this.$router.push({name: 'admin'})
     // this.redirectToUser('admin','admin')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("hjk"+err)
        this.$router.push('/oidc-callback-error') // Handle errors any way you want
      })
    },
    mounted(){
       
    }
    };
</script>
```

```html
<div>
                    <h1>Login successful</h1>
                    <p>Your browser should be redirected soon</p>
                   <!-- <p v-if="oidcUser">User: {{oidcUser}} </p>-->
                    
                       
                 </div>
```

I am using Asp.net core Identity for user management and for that the configuration is as below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
       // services.AddSpaStaticFiles();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
            .Build();
        string connectionStringData = config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:identityServerDataDB").Value;
        string connectionStringUser = config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:tisUserDataDB").Value;
        var migrationAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
        // for user add the DBcontext.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option => {
            option.UseSqlServer(connectionStringUser);
        });
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, TISUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
       // services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.AddIdentityServer(options=> {
                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                })
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()

                //.AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()

                // Configuration Store : Clients and Resource
                .AddConfigurationStore(option =>
                {
                    option.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionStringData, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
                })
                // Operational Store: tokens concent code etc.
                .AddOperationalStore(option => {
                    option.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionStringData, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
                });


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        InitializeIdentityServerDatabase(app);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        // app.UseSpaStaticFiles();


        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was in Cookies, the size was getting increased due to data, after decreasing it, it worked.

Comment: Would you tell us how did you decrease the size cookies? Or was it some extra data belongs to your applications?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using your application's login page. If so, you need to use the resource owner password flow
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html

(or)

If you use the Identity server's login page (sample MVC app from Identity server), you need to make it available at "/Account/Login" as per defaults

(or)

If you want your own login page for identity server, you can configure through

```
services.AddIdentityServer(setupAction =>
{
    setupAction.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Account#Login";
    setupAction.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Account#Logout";
    setupAction.UserInteraction.ErrorUrl = "/Account#Error";
})
```

Comment: Sir,Thanks for reply. the problem is coming after login , When it needs to redirect to the client application . 
1. Using IdentityServer4 Login screen with Asp.net core identity.  2. Implicit mode as it Vue.Js Application -have included the configuration in post. 3. I am using Vuex with OIDC . 4. the exception is on /connect/authorize/callback end point .